# customer_id = NULL in sales_order table?

Tags: magento2, database

I need to get orders data directly from the database. I have got all orders (about 18,000) since January 2020. I need to do a join to `customer_entity` however, I realized that about 300 records were missing.

By investigating further, I found out that the `customer_id` value is null for most of the records. Some records do have a `customer_id` column set but shipping address id fields are null. These latter occur for orders in `processing` status.

Most curious is the `null` value in the `customer_id` column of some orders, even in orders in `complete` status.

For the query, I need to join the customer's table so it is not an option to get all data from the `sales_order` table.

Any help? Thanks

Jaime

Comment: You can also get the customer from email saved in the quote table corresponding to the order. Please check if you have that corresponding to the order having null ids in order table.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Guest Orders are enabled for your store. Guest orders usually won't have customer Id set in order table.

Answer (score 0):

`customer_id` have foreign key. Technically, customers can be deleted. While customer deletion, all his orders sets customer_id to `NULL`.
You can check column `customer_is_guest` in `sales_order` to determine guest orders. You can use customer_email as alternative ID.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reason of this things.

1. The Order which you are refer is the `Guest` User Order.
2. The Order which you are refer, those customer are delete from the system.

So, no required to perform any join query, because if data is available then it on the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you join `sales_order_address` - one time for `address_type="shipping"` and one more join with `address_type="billing"`?

You can pull all customer information from there, regardless whether customer was signed in or this was a guest order.

Alternatively, you can take joined information from `sales_order_grid` table.

Answer (score 0):

@jstuardo Yes It's Magento 2 issue in the guest order.

Please create the patch and apply

Here is a commit: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e3aea78c3ac3eef0adb0b797949e4b0999d653f5

patch https://github.com/magento/magento2/files/10825539/magento-module-quote-model-quotemanagement-php.patch